# Can't connect to wifi: sta recv deauth reason code(15)

Tags: debian, wifi, dmesg, nmcli

I have a Wireless USB Adapter ZyXel NDW6605 which I'm trying to use on my Debian 10.

It uses Realtek RTL8812AU chipset so I installed the driver from here https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8812au and `frimware-realtek` package.

After that I could see wlan interfaces in my ifconfig output:

```
    wlp10s0f3u2: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
            ether ba:ec:a3:d9:e6:25  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
            RX packets 11  bytes 1705 (1.6 KiB)
            RX errors 0  dropped 61  overruns 0  frame 0
            TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
            TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
    
    wlxb8eca3d9e625: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
            ether b8:ec:a3:d9:e6:25  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
            RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
            RX errors 0  dropped 61  overruns 0  frame 0
            TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
            TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

and the list of available WiFi networks by using `nmcli dev wifi list`

The problem is that whenever I'm trying to connect to my network `nmcli dev wifi connect "xxx" password "yyy"` it constantly asks for my password and do not accept it.

Here is output from my `dmesg`:

```
[    5.766781] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp4s0: link becomes ready
[   31.696023] RTL8812: FirmwareDownload8812: wowland_mode:0 wowlan_wake_reason:0
[   64.694789] RTL8812: FirmwareDownload8812: wowland_mode:0 wowlan_wake_reason:0
[   85.414295] RTL8812: FirmwareDownload8812: wowland_mode:0 wowlan_wake_reason:0
[   91.483427] RTL8812: set ssid [xxx] fw_state=0x00000008
[   91.565989] RTL8812: start auth
[   91.570139] RTL8812: auth success, start assoc
[   91.574308] RTL8812: assoc success
[   91.577071] UpdateHalRAMask8812A => mac_id:0, networkType:0x0b, mask:0x0fffffff
                 ==> rssi_level:0, rate_bitmap:0x0f8ff015
[   91.658694] UpdateHalRAMask8812A => mac_id:0, networkType:0x0b, mask:0x0fffffff
                 ==> rssi_level:1, rate_bitmap:0x0f8f0000
[   99.502134] RTL8812: sta recv deauth reason code(15) sta:18:d6:c7:80:c5:3a
[  101.957678] RTL8812: FirmwareDownload8812: wowland_mode:0 wowlan_wake_reason:0
[  108.028308] RTL8812: set ssid [mim] fw_state=0x00000008
[  108.155110] RTL8812: start auth
[  108.158452] RTL8812: auth success, start assoc
[  108.163228] RTL8812: assoc success
[  108.166068] UpdateHalRAMask8812A => mac_id:0, networkType:0x0b, mask:0x0fffffff
                 ==> rssi_level:0, rate_bitmap:0x0f8ff015
[  110.063816] UpdateHalRAMask8812A => mac_id:0, networkType:0x0b, mask:0x0fffffff
                 ==> rssi_level:1, rate_bitmap:0x0f8f0000
[  136.740938] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp10s0f3u2: link is not ready
[  137.112065] RTL8812: FirmwareDownload8812: wowland_mode:0 wowlan_wake_reason:0
[  160.702950] RTL8812: FirmwareDownload8812: wowland_mode:0 wowlan_wake_reason:0
[  199.719092] RTL8812: FirmwareDownload8812: wowland_mode:0 wowlan_wake_reason:0
[  223.701597] RTL8812: FirmwareDownload8812: wowland_mode:0 wowlan_wake_reason:0
[  242.698232] RTL8812: FirmwareDownload8812: wowland_mode:0 wowlan_wake_reason:0
[  286.723999] RTL8812: FirmwareDownload8812: wowland_mode:0 wowlan_wake_reason:0
[  295.688256] RTL8812: FirmwareDownload8812: wowland_mode:0 wowlan_wake_reason:0
```

It states that auth is successful and then adds `sta recv deauth reason code(15)`.

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The alternative driver was found https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8812au.
This one actually worked